# Get woocommerce product category using Gutenberg getEntityRecords

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, gutenberg-blocks

Is it possible to get all product categories using Gutenberg `getEntityRecords()`?

I have found a code for getting post category as follows

```
var query = {per_page: 100}
categoriesList =  getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'category', query );
```

Can I alter the above code to get all woocommerce products category?

Comment: - Did you use WordPress REST API inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle to get the data via fetch request?

You can also look into the WooCommerce default blocks to get the idea how those blocks are requesting the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also searched the same thing. But at last I have decided to use the apiFetch for this tasks (following woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block plugin).

for example a sample use case :

```
const apiFetch = wp.apiFetch;
const { addQueryArgs } = wp.url;

const productCategories = (queryArgs) => {
    return apiFetch({
        path: addQueryArgs(`wc/store/products/categories`, {
            per_page: 0,
            ...queryArgs,
        }),
    });
};

productCategories().then((categories) => {
        console.log(categories);
});
```

Comment: thanks. With this method, you can also get product category image

Answer (score 1):

You were actually very close to getting `getEntityRecords` to work. The only issue was product categories are a different taxonomy than post categories.

Here's a full example utilizing the `useSelect` hook:

```
import { useSelect } from "@wordpress/data";

const { productCategories, isSearching } = useSelect((select) => {
    const { getEntityRecords, isResolving } = select("core");
    const query = { per_page: 100 };

    return {
        productCategories: getEntityRecords("taxonomy", "product_cat", query),
        isSearching: isResolving("getEntityRecords", [
            "taxonomy",
            "product_cat",
            query,
        ]),
    };
});
```